# access forbidden while clicking on login

Tags: php, forms

i am trying to create a login page for a website..whenever i am clicking on Login it is giving this error

**Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15**

i have attached my code with this.

**Login.php**

```
<?php
     require 'connect.inc.php';
     require 'core.inc.php';
     include 'loginform.php';
 ?>
```

**Loginform.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['u_name'])&& isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $u_name = $_POST['u_name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if(!empty($u_name)&&!empty($pass)) { 
        echo 'OK';
     }
    else {  
        echo 'Fields cannot be blank';
    }
} ?>

 <form action="<?php echo $currentfile;?>" method="POST">
     username: <input type="text" name="u_name">
     password : <input type="password" name="pass">
     <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
 </form>
```

Comment: Most probably you are trying to access the wrong file. Could you tell us what is the `action` attribute on the generated HTML form?

Comment: Where is `$currentfile` set and what is it supposed to write?

Comment: <?php
 $current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
 ?>

Comment: Is this `loginform.php` supposed to call itself or `login.php`?

Comment: login.php will call loginform.php

Comment: Oh forget it, it's being included. So if you are going to this page by itself it works just not on submission of the form?

Comment: If that is the case, try removing that action url: `<form action="" method="POST">` Make it blank and it should load itself.